# Why do my libgdx scene2d elements turn black?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, scene2d

I use libgdx for my app and skin sometimes just dissapears. I don't get any errors but all scene2d elements just turn black on android(on desktop they completely dissapear), they're stil fully functionable but are black(or invisible on dekstop). I didn't have this problem before but now when I started using libgdx's AssetManager it happens like every third time. By the way everything is fine in the beginning when i start the app and bug happens usually few seconds after.

Comment: Do you use the AssetManager to load a skin? Did you implement a Loader yourself? AFAIK there is no default loader for skins. Without any code we cannot help you anyhow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably disposed the skin somewhere . You must make sure with an AssetManager to dispose any resources only when the game stops .